# why my container div is not as big as the divs inside

Tags: css

I have a CSS question.

```
 <div id="middle">
        <div id="middle-left">
            <div id="middle-left-top">
                MLT
            </div>
            <div id="middle-left-bottom">
                MLB
            </div>
            <br class="clearFix">
        </div>
        <div id="middle-right">
                MLR
        </div>
        <br class="clearFix">

</div><!-- #middle-->
```

the example is at http://jsfiddle.net/Z2yeq/

my questions is why does  middle-left not contain the two divs inside?

I want middle-left to expand as middle-left-top and  middle-left-bottom
get taller

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Absoloutely-positioned elements are no longer part of the layout. The parent has no idea how large child items are.

If you want the parent to be as large as the positioned child items to need to calculate and set this using JavaScript.

In general you shouldn't use absolute-positioning for layouts. You should use FLOATS.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't is because you have it set to `position:absolute;` Remove position absolute to fix the problem.

```
#middle-left{
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 800px;
}
```